# Seeking help for this script Font Name

Tags: font-identification

I'm trying to find what font this is. I have check both Whatthefont and Font Squirrel but I can't find it as it is script font.

The letters below are Bride[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Watermelon Script](http://www.fontspace.com/mistis-fonts/watermelon-script-demo) via fontspace.com, the image of the question is slightly horizontally scaled.

[image: watermelonScript]

Comment: Thank you so much Danielillo .. that is exactly what i was looking for. Have a great day :)